# Google Apps Script how to search sheet column for matching text in email body

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I'm trying to search a column in a sheet to find the cell whose data is also contained in the body of an email.

I've put the timestamp from a google form submission in the body of an email along with other details of the submission. I'd like to then search the timestamp column on my sheet to find the cell with that matching timestamp that is now contained in the email body and return the row number.

This is what I have so far:

```
function updateSheetC() {
  //GMAIL QUERY
  const q = GmailApp.search('label:ProcessesTEST');

  const num = q[0].getMessageCount();
  const approvedeny = q[0].getMessages()[num - 1].getPlainBody();



  //SHEET INFO
  const id = '1FEP50qGUJcS6FJJkcPwX1cclrnOJ5Y6iRjKOkzoWc4A';
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
  const sheet_apprdeny = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');
```

Answer (score 0):

Find Rows in Timestamp Column that are included in the body of the emails return from a search.

```
function updateSheetC() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const hr = 1
  const sr = 2;
  const hs = sh.getRange(hr,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues().flat();
  const col = hs.reduce((a,h,i) => {a[h] = i + 1;return a},{});
  vs = sh.getRange(sr,col["TimeStamp"],sh.getLastRow() - sr + 1).getDisplayValues().flat();
  const ts = GmailApp.search('label:ProcessesTEST');
  let matches = [];
  const num = ts.forEach(t => {
    let ms = t.getMessages();
    ms.forEach(m => {
      vs.forEach((ts,i) => {
        if(m.getPlainBody().includes(ts)) {
          matches.push(i + sr);
        }
      });
    });
  });
  Logger.log(matches.join(","))
  return matches;
}
```

- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)
- [javascript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)
- [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)
- [GmailApp.Search](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#searchquery)

Comment: Thank you for the help! I keep getting an error when saving "Syntax error: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list line: 7 file: Update Sheet C.gs"
line 7 is
const col = hs.reduce((a,h,i) {a[h] = i + 1;return a},{});

Comment: Sorry I left the arrow out of the arrow notation

Comment: Thank you! Now I'm running into an error that says "hs is not defined" on that same line. I thought maybe it was supposed to be sh but when changing the line to read sh I get the error "sh.reduce is not a function". Do you know what that might be?